# Model Accepts Nesting Attributes without declaring that it accepts them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

everyone. So, I'm working on a basic Rails 4 application for practice, and I have a model for FriendCircle and a model for FriendCircleMembership. (the FriendCircleMembership's corresponding table is basically a join table).

In the console, I'm able to create a new FriendCircle object while passing in **:friend_circle_memberships_attributes**. This successfully inserts a new FriendCircle row into my table as well as inserting the proper rows into the FriendCircleMembership table.

The WEIRD thing is that, even if i comment out that the FriendCircle **accepts_nested_attributes for :friend_circle_memberships**, it still works. Is this because i am whitelisting it as a permission in the controller?

The other issue is that, even though i can successfully make the nested objects via the rails console, when i try making it through my html form it says my friend_circle_memberships_attributes is an unpermitted parameter. Not sure why this is happening. I check the incoming parameters and they look fine.

any help would be SWEEEEET. thanks.

Comment: did you restart console after changing in model?

Comment: i did. but thanks for the suggestion! ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined what the error was: One of my controllers for a nested attributes was validating the presence of the id of the controller it was nested under.

I'm assuming the validation occurs before an id is created, which makes sense, but im not 100%. So i just took out the validator and things worked.